# How to place a UIButton on another UIImageView which is a circular profile image?

Tags: ios, swift3, uiimageview, uibutton, autolayout

I have a profile settings page in my application so I need to need to place another `UIButton` on the profile image to choose the images from the camera or the photo gallery. So I'm confused how to place the constraints for it in storyboard.

The profile image grows with the screen size but I want the `UIButton` placed at the bottom to increase in size too.

The Constraints for the `UIImageView` which shows the profile photo:

[image: UIImageView constraints . It grows along with Size]

`UIButton` contains the image as:

[image: UIButton Image]

Now I want to place this button with image shown above to the profile image view.

What are the constraints required for it so that it is exactly at the bottom part of the profile image view and grows with size.

[image: The selected UI component is a Button . I need to set the constraints for this]

Answer (score 0):

Just change the constraint for the Y position to be `button.bottom = profileImage.bottom - 10` or whatever constant you want to put there. This way the button will always stay at the bottom of the image and resizing will be handled correctly by `Autolayout` based on your constraints.